# ¿Por qué no ejecuta una función dentro de una iteración?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Buenas,

con este sencillo código trato de leer un valor de una tabla ajena a la iteración, pero no me trae el valor pese a que sí lo encuentra.

```
for (var i in partes) {

            if (i > 0) {anterior = i - 1};

            for (var x in partes[i].lecturas) {

                partes[anterior].lecturas[x].consumo = partes[i].lecturas[x].lectura_actual - partes[anterior].lecturas[x].lectura_actual;


                criterio = buscarCriterio(partes[anterior].lecturas[x].codigo, partes[anterior].lecturas[x].mes);

                if (partes[anterior].lecturas[x].consumo > criterio.max ) {


                        partes[anterior].lecturas[x].cumple = false;


                };


            };

        };


            res.render('partes/resumen', {partes: partes, contadores: contadores, errors: []});

        }).catch(function(error){next(error)});


    }).catch(function(error){next(error)});

};





buscarCriterio = function(ContadorId, mes) {

    models.Criterio.find({

        where:      {ContadorId: ContadorId, mes: mes}

    }).then(function(criterio) {

        return criterio;

    }).catch(function(error){next(error)});


};
```

He sacado de la iteración la función buscarCriterio() para que su scope no esté dentro del bucle, pero sigue sin devolver el objeto 'criterio'. Dentro de criterio están los campos que necesito evaluar para ver si la condición if se cumple y el consumo de la lectura está dentro de tolerancias.

Se agradece ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu método `buscarCriterio` no está devolviendo nada. No puedes devolver un valor dentro de un callback hacia fuera de la función que la contiene. Para eso puedes usar una [`promesa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promesa):

```
buscarCriterio = function(ContadorId, mes) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    models.Criterio.find({
      where: {
        ContadorId: ContadorId,
        mes: mes
      }
    }).then(function(criterio) {
      resolve(criterio);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      reject(error)
    });
  });
};
```

Solo he modificado un poco la función para devolver una [`promesa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promesa) que **puede contener** el criterio o el error que lanza Sequelize. Si todo va bien, entonces, usando `then` obtienes el criterio, caso contrario, con `cacth` obtienes el error en la consulta:

```
for (let i in partes) {
  if (i > 0) {
    anterior = i - 1;
  }
  for (let x in partes[i].lecturas) {
    partes[anterior].lecturas[x].consumo = partes[i].lecturas[x].lectura_actual - partes[anterior].lecturas[x].lectura_actual;
    buscarCriterio(partes[anterior].lecturas[x].codigo, partes[anterior].lecturas[x].mes)
      .then((criterio) => {
        if (partes[anterior].lecturas[x].consumo > criterio.max) {
          partes[anterior].lecturas[x].cumple = false;
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // manejar el error de Sequelize
      });
  }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que he cambiado `var i` por `let i` para que la variable de control `i` tenga un ámbito de ejecución ya que se estará usando dentro de un callback (el de la promesa). Si no haces ésto, siempre se referenciará dentro del callback al último elemento del array que iteras en los `for`. Lee sobre [`closures`](https://gist.github.com/amysimmons/3d228a9a57e30ec13ab1) para entender más sobre éste comportamiento.

Comment: Es correcto así como dices. Lo único que tuve que actualizar nodejs > v4 para que soporte la declaración let.